# Mqtt-Kafka connector authentication

Tags: mqtt, apache-kafka-connect

I need help because I'm new about kafka and mqtt.
I will try to briefly explain the architecture I am using.
I'm using the Confluent 5.3.1 platform and I configured a connector (source mqtt connector) that transfers data from the mqtt broker to kafka broker.
In order to connect to the mqtt broker I need a Json Web Token and I have no idea how to do it. I've read the Confluent documentation but i can't find any possible solutions.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation [for the connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-mqtt/mqtt-source-connector/mqtt_source_connector_config.html) it looks like it only support password-based authentication, not JWT.

Comment: I read this document (https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/security.html ) and it seems that something can be done (am I wrong?) but I can't implement it.

Comment: That's authentication to the Kafka Connect cluster itself, whereas your question is about authentication to the MQTT broker.

Comment: ok, thanks. So, the mqtt source connector only allows to set password and username to connect to the mqtt broker but not using an IDP to do that. it's right?

Comment: That's my understanding, yes.

Comment: Just a curiosity: I need to set the field mqtt.server.uri using a websocket protocol. So i have something like that ws://<ip-addess>:port. 
I observed that maybe it does not works because i can't read data. It is possible to solve this?